# Test failed for Date of Birth

Tags: python, django

I am a beginner in python-django coding. Currently I'm at the **challenge** part of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Testing. My tests are going well except for **def test_form_date_of_death_initially_set_to_expected_date(self)**. The error is **AssertionError: datetime.date(1900, 1, 1) != datetime.date(2020, 6, 11)** From what I understand the 1900,1,1 is the date that return to me after the function is done checking. But the problem is I have no idea how this date is coming out. I check thru my files and I cant see any codes setting it as 1900, 1, 1. So is this a default date if it is not set? If it is default by nature, how come i set test author date of death, it is still coming out 1900, 1, 1. Appreciate if anyone could help me. Thanks

```
class AuthorCreateTest(TestCase):
        def setUp(self):
            # Create a user
            test_user1 = User.objects.create_user(username='testuser1', password='1X<ISRUkw+tuK')
            test_user2 = User.objects.create_user(username='testuser2', password='2HJ1vRV0Z&3iD')
    
            test_user1.save()
            test_user2.save()
    
            # Give test_user2 permission to renew books.
            permission = Permission.objects.get(name='Set book as returned')
            test_user2.user_permissions.add(permission)
            test_user2.save()
    
            # Create a book
            test_author = Author.objects.create(first_name='John', last_name='Smith', date_of_death='2006-06-11')
            
        def test_redirect_if_not_logged_in(self):
            response = self.client.get(reverse('author-create'))
            self.assertRedirects(response, '/accounts/login/?next=/catalog/author/create/')
    
        def test_forbidden_if_logged_in_but_not_correct_permission(self):
            login = self.client.login(username='testuser1', password='1X<ISRUkw+tuK')
            response = self.client.get(reverse('author-create'))
            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 403)
    
        def test_logged_in_with_permission(self):
            login = self.client.login(username='testuser2', password='2HJ1vRV0Z&3iD')
            response = self.client.get(reverse('author-create'))
            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    
        def test_uses_correct_template(self):
            login = self.client.login(username='testuser2', password='2HJ1vRV0Z&3iD')
            response = self.client.get(reverse('author-create'))
            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
            self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'catalog/author_form.html')

    def test_form_date_of_death_initially_set_to_expected_date(self):
        login = self.client.login(username='testuser2', password='2HJ1vRV0Z&3iD')
        response = self.client.get(reverse('author-create'))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

        expected_initial_date = datetime.date(2020, 6, 11)
        response_date = response.context['form'].initial['date_of_death']
        response_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(response_date, "DD/MM/YYYY").date()
        self.assertEqual(response_date, expected_initial_date)

    def test_redirects_to_detail_view_on_success(self):
        login = self.client.login(username='testuser2', password='2HJ1vRV0Z&3iD')
        response = self.client.post(reverse('author-create'),
                                    {'first_name': 'Christian Name', 'last_name': 'Surname'})
        # Manually check redirect because we don't know what author was created
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
        self.assertTrue(response.url.startswith('/catalog/author/'))
```

Comment: You are right, your date is not set, so it takes the default value.

Comment: I wonder if it's because you do `date_of_death='2006-06-11'` and then `strptime(response_date, "DD/MM/YYYY")` which might not be what you intended.

Comment: Ok but how come when I set the date of death to 2006-06-11, the test still fail and its returning me 1900, 1, 1? @FrédéricPerron

Comment: If that's the case, can u recommend me a correct way to check the date of death that I had set for user 2 ? @BrettJeffreson

Comment: Well, according to the docs for strptime, the second argument is for telling the function how to parse the input and since you're inputting `2006-06-11` and telling it to parse that with `DD/MM/YYYY`, it will give you the default. As per the docs: `The default values used to fill in any missing data when more accurate values cannot be inferred are (1900, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1)`. Perhaps try putting the correct second argument that matches the format of the input.

Comment: You are using `response.context['form'].initial['date_of_death']`.  That fetches your DEFAULT date, not the date the user entered.  Did you set a default date for that field?

Comment: I am having this error now. ValueError: day is out of range for month
 This the part I changed only: 
response_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(response_date, "11/06/2006").date() 
@BrettJeffreson

Comment: Guys, I managed to solve the issue. Thanks guys !